# looking for a regex that will find any second set of square brackets in a file name

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex pattern that will find any second set of square brackets in a file name (if one exists) and remove it and its contents. must be able to cope with all possible variations in file names. For use in File Renamer.

For example,

> Eman_Elif [abcdefg 01] txet [XYZ-567].txt

Result

> Eman_Elif [abcdefg 01] txet .txt

Comment: For future reference **please post what you've tried** in addition to what you are 'looking for'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the first set up to the second, then replace the entire match with the captured first part:

```
Search: (\[.*?\].*?)\[.*?\]
Replace: $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the option Find using Regular Expressions in File Renamer. You can use the following.

```
Find: \[[^]]*](\.[^.]+)$
Replace: $1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use regex to handle this, something along these lines seems to work:

```
s/^(.*?)(?:(\[[^\]]*?\].*?)(?:\[[^\]]*?\]))(.*)$/$1$2$3/
```

The requirement "must be able to cope with all possible variations in the filename", is pretty wide-open. For example, are mismatched or nested brackets possible?

```
Eman_Elif [abcdefg [xyz] 01] txet [XYZ-567].txt
Eman_Elif [abcdefg [[xyz 01] txet [XYZ-567].txt
Eman_Elif [abcdefg xyz ]01] txet]  [X[123]YZ-567].txt
```